# Bit of a brain teaser: Custom logic strings with C# classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, logic

So, my basic set up is like so: I have items, which are restricted to different classes. These items have effects, which are also restricted to different classes. For example, I might have an item that may only be wielded by elves, while another item might be wielded by everyone, but gives specific bonuses/effects to elves.

Here's a Restriction class:

```
public class Restriction {
    private int _base_id = 0;
    private bool _qualify = true;
    public Restriction() { }
    // ... Base_ID and Qualify getters and setters here
    public virtual bool Check(int c) {
        if(_qualify) { return c == _base_id; }
        else { return c != _base_id; }
}
```

A child of the Restriction class might be RaceRestriction, which only overrides the constructor:

```
public RaceRestriction(reference.races r, bool qual) {
    Base_ID = (int)r; Qualify = qual;
}
```

reference.races r is an enum in a reference file. The idea here is that I can extend this "Restriction" syntax to any class that I define in the reference file -- so I can make Restrictions on race, class, stats, whatever I need.

So, this all culminates later, when I define (for example) an item, which has restrictions on who can equip it.

Below is a snippet from the Equipment class, where I define a piece of equipment for later use (hopefully it's readable as is):

```
public Equipment() { 
    ...
    _master_equipment_list[1] = new Equipment {
        Name = "Sword",
        Description = "It's just a sword for demonstration",
        Stats = {
            new Attribute {
                Stat_Modifier = new KeyValuePair<reference.stats, int>(reference.stats.ATTACK, 5),
                Restrictions = {
                    new RaceRestriction(reference.races.TROLL, false)
                }
            }
        },
        Restrictions = {
            new ClassRestriction(reference.class.WARRIOR, true)
        }
    }
```

So the idea behind this is that using this system, I've defined a sword that can only be used by warriors (base warrior true restriction on the item), and it gives 5 attack to any trolls wielding it.

What I've cornered myself into is that this will only work for either logical AND or logical OR strings of thought. Say my item says "warriors can use this" and it says "elves can use this." Do I really mean "warriors or elves" or do I mean "warrior elves?"

That distinction, I think, is going to be necessary -- so I need to attach some logic to each restriction and make, essentially, I think, sets of restrictions that are tied to one another, that string with other sets of restrictions, etc., but I feel like that will get out of hand very fast.

Is there a better way I can do this?

Comment: Nice to see a very different type of question.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than defining specific restriction classes, I would design this by defining an interface called `IRestrictable` to be implemented by the `Equipment` classes. This interface would contain at least one method called `CheckEligibility` (or similar) which would return a bool. Your equipment class would then be free to use whatever logic expression it liked to come up with the answer, based on whatever inputs you wanted and whatever information the class had available at the time. You could have several methods on the interface if you need to check restrictions under different circumstances. You would be free to implement specific classes deriving from `Equipment` for specific types of equipment that had complicated rules.